# Error while querying parquet table in presto

Tags: apache-spark, hive, presto

A hive parquet table is created over a spark dataframe saved in parquet format.
I am able to query the parquet data in my parquet table.

But while querying in presto, it shows an error: "Query 20200817_061959_00150_nztin failed: Can not read value at 0 in block 0 in file"

I am not using any decimal fields. Most of my fields are of string type and some of them are date and timestamp type.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: I got the result. I was getting the error because presto is not order preserved.When i set "hive.parquet.use-column-names = true" this property in hive, the query has been worked. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Oh... you can follow https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1558 for this one.